# use AngularJS service for Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have AngularJS service :

```
var id = 'authService';

angular.module('app')
    .service(id, ['$http', '$q', '$injector', 'storageSvc', 'notifyHub', 'sysSettings', '$rootScope', 'crudSvc', authService]);
```

and would like to use it inside my angular component SignInComponent :

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Account } from '../../../../shared/models/account';
import { AuthService } from "../../../../shared/angularJS-upgraded-providers";

@Component({
  selector: 'sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html'
})

export class SignInComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(AuthService) private authService: any) {
    this.authService = authService;
  }

  model = new Account('admin02', 'Admin@002', true);

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.login(this.model).then(response => {
      if (response != null) {
            alert("Seems it works");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

For this purpose I created angularJS-upgraded-providers.ts file :

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
export const AuthService = new InjectionToken<any>('authService');

export function authServiceFactory(i: any) {
  return i.get('authService');
}

export const authServiceProvider = {
  provide: AuthService,
  useFactory: authServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};
```

and trying to reuse it inside app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { SignInComponent } from "./modules/login/components/sign-in/sign-in.component";
import { authServiceProvider } from './shared/angularJS-upgraded-providers';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SignInComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    SignInComponent
  ],
  providers: [authServiceProvider
  ],
  bootstrap: [SignInComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
  }
}
```

My start file - main.ts looks like this :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But when I am trying to run my program I have an error :

```
ERROR Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.
    at injectorFactory (static.js:690)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10956)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10910)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10892)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10958)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10910)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10892)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12619)
    at createClass (core.js:12481)
```

Could please anybody provide algorithm or at least give an idea what i am doing wrong and why i am getting the error : Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set? 
Which template or pattern I could use to be able to consume AngularJS service inside my Angular5 app?
AngularJS version : 1.6.8,
Angular version : 5.2.11
Thank you for your time

Comment: you didn't enclosed authService in string quotes ,Please check  it's a typo or not.

Comment: in which file it should be enclosed? Thanks for your attention to my problem

Comment: inside  angular.module('app')
    .service dependencies